# Count how many check boxes checked in Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

How to count how many boxes checked in Angular 2/4 using typescript. It should show the count of the check boxes checked, and if unchecked it should decrement to 0.

My example, data coming from server, which I loop through:

I know how to do it using foreach function in Angularjs, but cant understand how to do this in Typescript, generally I have to replace angular foreach method with Typescript foreach method? Need help

app.ts

```
  data = [
     {"name":"jason"},
     {"name":"james"},
     {"name":"josh"},
     {"name":"joshua"}
          ];



calculateChecked = function() {            
 let count = 0;

  angular.forEach(this.data, function(value) {    //don't work in typescript
    if(value.checked)
      count++;
  });

  return count;
   };
  };
```

app.htm

```
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of data">
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="user.checked"/>
    {{user.name}}
    </li>


    <p>total checked: {{calculateChecked()}}</p>
```

should show:

[image]

And if unchecked should show 0

```
  <div class="sasha-ui-list" #em *ngFor="let email of emails; let i=index"
   (click)="onAddtoMessage(email)"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-lg-1">
  <input class="magic-checkbox sasha_checkbox" name="emails" type="checkbox" 
  id="{{email.id}}" value="email" [checked]="checkboxFlag"> <label for="
 {{email.id}}"></label> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make it to 0 when clicked as below,

```
 changed(){
    this.count = 0;
    this.data.forEach(item=>{
      console.log(item)
      if(item.checked){
        this.count= this.count+1
      }  
    } )
  }


<ul> <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of data">

<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" (ngModelChange)="changed()"/>
{{user.name}}
</li>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7IscAC60rSwrkVSSVnm?p=preview)**

Comment: great answer and example, but I can't add key checked to the array

Comment: @OleksandrFedorov can you clone the array and append a property?

Comment: don't really want to do this, as I will have loads of data

Comment: can you list me out all constraints please :(

Comment: is there are any way to count without adding property to array, as I will have custom data coming from server. Each object is linked to a check box. What I need to do is count increment/decrement how many boxes selected. Cant realy understand how it was counted here without adding checked property http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ad7qerU7MMQBZApIhkx?p=preview

Comment: how are you keeping track of the values that are selected?

Comment: <div class="sasha-ui-list" #em *ngFor="let email of emails;  let i=index" (click)="onAddtoMessage(email)">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <input class="magic-checkbox sasha_checkbox" name="emails" type="checkbox" id="{{email.id}}" value="email" [checked]="checkboxFlag">
                    <label for="{{email.id}}"></label>
                </div>  I have for loop, to get the value I just pass in object (email) it return me object selectedf onclick

Comment: updated answer, checked = checkboxFlag, which is set to boolean, I use it to check/uncheck all boxes

Comment: If you using Angular 4, you might get an error, so just change to this  if (item['checked']) {

Answer (score 2):

not tested code, but something like this should work, if data is an array

```
 this.data.map((value) => {
     if(value.checked)
       count++;   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for..of loop:

```
this.count: number = 0;
for (let datum of data) {
 if(dataum.checked) count++;
}
```

And the markup to..

```
<ul> <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of data">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" (ngModelChange)="changed()"/>
{{user.name}}
</li>

<p>total checked: {{count}}</p>
```